TikZ: how prevent darker fill in overlapping regions?
In this TikZ picture, how do I prevent the overlapping regions from becoming darker than the rest? I want the overlap to be the same uniform color as the rest of the regions.
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]]% Union of two overlapping irregular regions
  % First region
  \fill[red, opacity=0.3] plot [smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates {(-1,1) (1,2) (2,0) (1,-1.5) (-1,-2) (-2,-0.5)};
  \draw[thick] plot [smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates {(-1,1) (1,2) (2,0) (1,-1.5) (-1,-2) (-2,-0.5)};
  \node at (-.5,0.75) {$A$};
  
  % Second region
  \fill[red, opacity=0.3] plot [smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates {(1,1.5) (3,2) (4,0) (3,-1) (2,-2) (1,-0.5)};
  \draw[thick] plot [smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates {(1,1.5) (3,2) (4,0) (3,-1) (2,-2) (1,-0.5)}; 

\node at (3,0.5) {$B$};

 \node at (0.5, -3) {$A \cup B$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



You could use a transparency group:
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]% Union of two overlapping irregular regions
  % First region
  \begin{scope}[transparency group,opacity=0.3]
  \fill[red] plot [smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates {(-1,1) (1,2) (2,0) (1,-1.5) (-1,-2) (-2,-0.5)};
  % Second region
  \fill[red] plot [smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates {(1,1.5) (3,2) (4,0) (3,-1) (2,-2) (1,-0.5)};
  \end{scope}
    \draw[thick] plot [smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates {(1,1.5) (3,2) (4,0) (3,-1) (2,-2) (1,-0.5)}; 
  \draw[thick] plot [smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates {(-1,1) (1,2) (2,0) (1,-1.5) (-1,-2) (-2,-0.5)};
  \node at (-.5,0.75) {$A$};
\node at (3,0.5) {$B$};

 \node at (0.5, -3) {$A \cup B$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


... or just not use opacity:
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]% Union of two overlapping irregular regions
  \fill[red!30] plot [smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates {(-1,1) (1,2) (2,0) (1,-1.5) (-1,-2) (-2,-0.5)};
  % Second region
  \fill[red!30] plot [smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates {(1,1.5) (3,2) (4,0) (3,-1) (2,-2) (1,-0.5)};
  \draw[thick] plot [smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates {(1,1.5) (3,2) (4,0) (3,-1) (2,-2) (1,-0.5)}; 
  \draw[thick] plot [smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates {(-1,1) (1,2) (2,0) (1,-1.5) (-1,-2) (-2,-0.5)};
  \node at (-.5,0.75) {$A$};
  \node at (3,0.5) {$B$};
  \node at (0.5, -3) {$A \cup B$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Yes, eliminating opacity certainly is simpler!

Transparency groups are a useful general solution, but for a simple case like this you can also just fill a single path that includes both regions:
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]]% Union of two overlapping irregular regions
  \path[draw, thick, fill=red, fill opacity=0.3] 
  plot [smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates {(-1,1) (1,2) (2,0) (1,-1.5) (-1,-2) (-2,-0.5)}
  plot [smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates {(1,1.5) (3,2) (4,0) (3,-1) (2,-2) (1,-0.5)};
  
  \node at (-.5,0.75) {$A$};
  \node at (3,0.5) {$B$};
  \node at (0.5, -3) {$A \cup B$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Note that there is no semicolon after the first plot command, so the two regions comprise a single path. (I have also combined the drawing and filling into a single command.) You can even fill just the disjoint union of the two regions by adding even odd rule as an option to the path.
